# Next JS v13 Getting Image from the server Error

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am trying to get the image from the server but I always encounter this error that next js cannot read the url so it can display the image inside the page , i tried many solutions in next.config.js file but it doesn't work here is the solution i did but it doesn't work

```
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: '1337',
        pathname: 'localhost:1337/',
      },
    ],
  },
```

here is the error in the browser :

> Error: Invalid src prop (http://localhost:1337/images/aa.png) on
> `next/image`, hostname "localhost" is not configured under images in
> your `next.config.js` See more info:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

here is my code inside next js page.js :

```
 <Image src={(process.env.SERVER + cat.img).replaceAll(/\\/g, "/")} width={"200"} height={"200"}/>
```

the env server is just the url of localhost:1337/ inside the next.config.js file , how can i render the image from my server and display it on the screen ?

Comment: Try setting the src to `/images/aa.png` rather than the full absolute path.

Comment: i tried but still not working , but the url is localhost:3000 not localhost:1337 so it doesn't detect the url of the server and when i manually put it i get the error above , not sure what to do

Comment: Hey, geniar90, did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 1):

your remote pattern defines an 'https' host, but you are loading the image using src prop with 'http'. I would suggest updating to use the 'http' protocol:

```js
images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'http',
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: '1337',
        pathname: 'localhost:1337/',
      },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: yea i tried that and i tried this code inside the frontend too but it doesn't work at all :

images.remotePatterns[0].pathname + cat.img

Comment: the images working fine inside the normal html <img /> tag but not working in <Image /> next js tag

Comment: If I'm understanding the next.config.js file, this is basically an 'allowed hosts' list. so you would need to load the image in the way that you have, but since it is using next/image to do the loading, it needs to use an allowed host. since you are serving the page via http, it will continue to use http, but you don't have an allowed http host listed, you have an https. your error states http as the protocol, not https 'Invalid src prop ( 'http://' localhost:1337/images/aa.png) '

Comment: I tried to edit the url inside the frontend & tried to edit images inside next.config.js still not working , but its working perfectly inside <img /> html tag , not sure if its a bug inside next/image or not .

Comment: ok, I'd like to help a bit more. when you say that it works in an <img> tag, what is the literal src value? and what is the url of the page that this is on? please include http: or https:

Comment: i am using express server it renders the image url from the database , i am working locally inside my pc , the url is something like this ( http:// localhost:1337/images/aa.png ) the exact same code works fine in html img tag but not working at all at Image from next js  , i also tried the loader parameter but it always refuse because i am using a function , not sure if Image has a bug in next v13 or not

Comment: with respect, http and https will be treated differently, so firstly understanding how to access the image with the correct url is important. From what you are communicating, it does seem that your express server is only serving http requests, and not https. With that in mind, your remotePatterns is set up to use https, which is invalid and can't be used. so you should update that definition to just be http. don't change your front end code, it is trying to use http already via process.env.SERVER which is not your remotePatterns definition.

Comment: you can also try to remove the remotePatterns entirely. because it is served at the same address.  Thank you for the opportunity to try and help.  I'm not likely to be able to add anything from this point. I hope you are able to get this sorted out. It might be a good idea to run through the onboarding process again, maybe v13 has changed things for the worse: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started

Comment: I did everything possible also i tried every solution online but it doesn't work , maybe its a bug inside the appDir or its a bug inside the Image component , i will try to report a bug inside github next js and see what the developers would say , I am sure everything is correct in my case